# In Drupal 7 Commerce, is there a way to populate an anonymous user's profile billing/shipping address data during checkout?

Tags: 7, users, commerce

This is for Commerce Core. Not Kickstart, but it can also apply.

Upon completing checkout with an anonymous user in Drupal Commerce. There is no billing / shipping data populated in the user's profile. What modules or rules are needed to have the user's billing / shipping address profile pre-filled upon successful checkout?

This is after the anonymous user completes a successful checkout and an account is automatically generated for them.

Comment: Targeting a anonymous user profile is out of question, how can you identify this UID of any user if they are not logged in?

Though if email ID exists user get asked to enter password, and if they do...fields are populated with used address fields data...

Comment: i revised the question.

Comment: Got the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to set the default billing / shipping customer profiles for the newly created user to be the ones that were just used in checkout. I don't know if there's a Rules action for that, but if not, that sounds like a good feature request for the Commerce Addressbook module. If there is, then you just need to add a checkout completion rule to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [address book module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook) and [simple submodule](https://www.drupal.org/node/1697546#comment-9858193).

1) Install address book as usually.
2) Enable a simple submodule (see above).
3) Create a field_address in user profile

**Optionaly**: 
- Install Commerce addressbook extra  
- Add a simple js to synchronize a field_address and commerce_addressbook fields on registration (and user edit) page.
**All done**.